# How to unbind PanResponder for <View>

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I unbind PanResponder on a View. Also, how do I unmount a View altogether?

I tried to remove it by setting it to null but that would break in case of further renders.

```
handlePanResponderEnd: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
  if (Math.abs(this.translate) > width/4){
    var setoff = -(2 * width);
    var that = this;
    this.nextItem = <View style={styles.container} ><Story data={this.data[that.state.currentItem + 2]} /></View>;
    this.setState({ left: setoff, currentItem: this.state.currentItem + 1 });
    // this.setPanResponder();          
  } else {
    this.setState({ left: this.translate });    
  }     
}
```

Comment: If you created it with this._panResponder = PanResponder.create() have you tried just setting this._panResponder to undefined?

Comment: can't do that. there are other entities using it. i just want to unbind this class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using conditional rendering?
You can wrap or not your component with Animated.View depending on a value you check. Something like this:

```
{renderAnimated ?
<Animated.View>{this.renderMyContent()}<Animated.View>
: {this.renderMyContent()}
}
```

Or you can set your PanResponder const to a PanResponder.create() or null depending

```
const panResponder = shouldPanResponder ? PanResponder.create({...}) : null
```

Hope it helps.